# Using NumPy arrays as 2D mathematical vectors?

Tags: mathematics, vector, python, data-structure, pygame

Right now I'm using lists as position, velocity, and acceleration vectors in my game.  Is that a better option than using NumPy's arrays (not the standard library's) as vectors (with `float` data types)?  I'm frequently adding vectors and changing their values directly, then placing the values in these vectors into a Pygame `Rect`.  The vector is used for position (because `Rect`s can't hold floats, so we can't go "between" pixels), and the `Rect` is used for rendering (because Pygame will only take in `Rect`s for rendering positions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560226/770038) recommends [gameobjects](http://code.google.com/p/gameobjects/) which has a Vector2 class.  I'm not sure how it will interact with Pygame's Rects.

Comment: Hrm.  A little bit of `timeit` experimentation shows that this isn't actually faster.  Well, `gameobjects` ought to be useful anyway.  Thanks!